# How to use multi FOR loop in a View file of MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem when trying to use multiple FOR loop (for in for). The error message is:

> **Parser Error Message:** The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the
>   "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters
>   are being interpreted as markup.

Here is my code, the problem come from the first for :( .

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
@for (int q = 0; q < quanList.Count; q++) {     
    <tr>
        <td>@quanList[q]</td>

        @for (int s = 0; s < sizeList.Count; s++) {         
            <td><input type="text" name="txtval" style="width:80px" /></td>
        }
    </tr>
}   
</table>
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion and ideas.

I want to show a table with dynamic rows and columns, two list has been created from controller and parse to view via ViewBag:

```
@{
List<string> sizeList = (List<string>)ViewBag.SizeList;
List<string> quanList = (List<string>)ViewBag.QuanList;
```

}

Comment: Is it due to the `name="txtval_@q_@s"` part? Maybe those `@` characters are causing an issue.

Comment: No, it's not. I have changed the name to "txtval", and same problem :(. Thanks you

Comment: post the entire page, maybe the { creating rpoblem is outside the snippet you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
@{List<int> quanList = new List<int>();
  List<int> sizeList = new List<int>();
}
for (int q = 0; q < quanList.Count(); q++) {
<tr>
    <td>@quanList[q]
    </td>
    for (int s = 0; s < sizeList.Count(); s++){
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtval_@q_@s" style="width: 80px" />
    </td>
    }
</tr>
} }
</table>
```

Try this :

Try renaming this `@q` `@s` to something else. If you mix them up , MVC will treat as a normal `@` for example `example@example.com` .

```
{int textFieldName = "txtval_" + q +
        "_" + s;
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="@textFieldName" style="width: 80px" />
        </td>
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your naming suggestion :). But my problem is still here :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the input name to the following:

```
<input type="text" name="txtval_@(q)_@(s)" style="width:80px" />
```

Those extra brackets should fix it

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `@` symbols by using double `@`:

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtval_@@q_@@s" style="width:80px" /></td>
```

Or if you require the q and s values, you can include brackets:

```
<td><input type="text" name="txtval_@(q)_@(s)" style="width:80px" /></td>
```